# Drupal site only shows text

Tags: drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 site which has been working greatly until now, but now it just show only text on front and back-end also. I tried to clear the cache and change appearance theme but didn't fix it. I tried to monitor  in chrome, by refreshing and monitor Network and Console windows and found in /sites/default/files/ most jpg and png files are not found. But no one has touched the site until we found out it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Drupal log and your webserver logs. Probably you have problem with file permissions.

Comment: here is the server log says .....please help...................'PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home3/drupal7/public_html/mysite.com/modules/system/system.install' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home3/drupal7/public_html/mysite.com/includes/install.core.inc on line 241'